# how to set date and time limitation in Date Time Picker from Now to 1 Month from Now?

Tags: ios, swift, date, datepicker

I now that there is a thread that discussing about minimum and maximum date time in here [Minimum and maximum date in UIDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494174/minimum-and-maximum-date-in-uidatepicker/29414462)

but I am a beginner now in programming, and I have little bit confused with date and time object. I have tried but I can't set up my date time picker properly. So I want to set my date time picker to have minimum and maximum limited time.

the minimum is Now, and the maximum is 1 month from now. what code do I have to use? Thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxXUX.png

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
self.datePicker.minimumDate = Date()

self.datePicker.maximumDate =  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 30 , to:Date())!
```

or

```
self.datePicker.maximumDate =  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1 , to:Date())!
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the date math skills of `Calendar`. It calculates the same day in the next month. If the day does not exist (for example Feb 30) it returns the next closest available date.

```
let now = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dayComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: now)
let maximumDate = calendar.nextDate(after: now, matching: dayComponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a `Date` exactly one month in the future from now (taking into account different month lengths), you can use `Date.date(byAdding:value:to:)`, e.g. as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42569084/5471218). You'd take the result and set it as `maximumDate` of your picker.